# Liferay change Full name logged in

Tags: liferay

I want to change name appear in Liferay portal after logged in.
If i logged in Liferay, it has "Full name (Sign out)" on the top right of  page.

Can I change the Full name to another name I config?

I have build a Liferay-login-portlet already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a hook for the file **/html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp** replacing in this code...

```
<liferay-util:buffer var="userName">
    <img alt="<liferay-ui:message key="manage-my-account" />" src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)) %>" />

    <span class="user-full-name">
        <%= HtmlUtil.escape(user.getFullName()) %>
    </span>
</liferay-util:buffer>
```

where it says *user.getFullName()* with that you want. For example, to use the user nick, use this

```
<liferay-util:buffer var="userName">
    <img alt="<liferay-ui:message key="manage-my-account" />" src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(user.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)) %>" />

    <span class="user-full-name">
        <%= HtmlUtil.escape(user.getScreenName()) %>
    </span>
</liferay-util:buffer>
```

Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: @le nam welcome to stackoverflow. Consider accepting the answer instead of commenting when it helped (upvote if you like). That's the currency used on stackoverflow to say "thanks"

Comment: I have upvote the answer already but

 "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."